# Do URLs that only consist of an id, for example, a timestamp, have a chance to succeed in SEO?

Tags: url-rewriting, url-parameters, technical-seo, clean-urls, url-slug

For example:
`https://example.com/12345678912/` **vs** `https://example.com/keyword1-some-words/`

Is URL still an important factor for Google?

Comment: They can succeed, but they are a little hobbled. A very common compromise is to include both the ID and some words - eg `https://example.com/12345678912/keyword1-some-words`  - You can then use rewrite rules or a proxy to strip the keywords and produce the article based on the ID.

Answer (score 4):

I always lean towards descriptive urls.

- They are easier for the users to understand.
- They are easier to maintain.
- And they have a tiny bit of impact on ranking.

[Google : URL structure best practices for Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/url-structure) has this to say

> Recommended: Simple, descriptive words in the URL:
> `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation`
>
> Not recommended: Unreadable, long ID numbers in the URL:
> `https://www.example.com/index.php?id_sezione=360&sid=3a5ebc944f41daa6f849f730f1`

[Moz : Why do URLs matter for SEO?](https://moz.com/learn/seo/url) has this to say

> **2. Rankings**
> URLs are a minor ranking factor search engines use when determining a particular page or resource's relevance to a search query. While they do give weight to the authority of the overall domain itself, keyword use in a URL can also act as a ranking factor.
>
> While using a URL that includes keywords can improve your site's search visibility, URLs themselves generally do not have a major impact on a page’s ability to rank. So, while it’s worth thinking about, don’t create otherwise unuseful URLs simply to include a keyword in them.

Comment: [Moz, formerly SEOmoz](https://moz.com/about) has no relationship with [Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/), the makers of Firefox.

Comment: StackExchange has a nice method of using a descriptive name in the URL, but ignoring it in favor of the ID. If I take the URL to this question, and modify the descriptive part, it will [still work, and redirect to the correct description](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/143051/fake-fake-fake-fake) (hover over link to see) This allows the code to find posts easily as an ID lookup in the database, but still having information for the user to see before opening.

Comment: @ColeTobin it's not all roses. The technique can be abused to create deceptive links.